# How to #define a character in C++

Tags: c++

I need to define a character in C++. Right now I have:

```
#define ENQ (char)5
```

Is there a way to define a character similar to how you can define a long using the `l` suffix (e.g. `5l`)?

Answer (score 5):

The cast is fine, it has no run-time impact, but you can define character constants of any value directly using the `\x` escape sequence to specify characters by their hexadecimal character code - useful for non-printing or extended characters.

```
#define ASCII_ENQ `\x5`
```

But in C++ you'd do better to use a `const` (which has explicit type):

```
static const char ASCII_ENQ = 5 ;
```

or

```
static const char ASCII_ENQ = '\x5' ;
```

if you strive for complete type agreement (not really necessary).

Answer (score 1):

that would be a character literal `'a'` for instance:

```
#define ALPHA 'a'
#define FIVE_CHAR '5'
```

Comment: How does 5 equate to `'a'`?

Comment: @Clifford It doesn't. I didn't interpret the question as to get the actual 5, but in a more generic way, how to define a character.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an [User-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) and write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

const char operator ""_ch( unsigned long long i) {
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char enq = 5_ch;
    char alpha = 65_ch;

    cout << alpha << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

But it's a bit of overkill for something you can more easily express with:

```
const char ENQ = 5;
```

Unless you are actually trying to do things as tricky as:

```
#include <iostream>

// convert a number (a figure) to its ASCII code
const char operator ""_ch( unsigned long long i) {
    return i < 10 ? i + 48 : 48;
}

int main() {
    char num_as_char = 5_ch;

    std::cout << num_as_char << '\n';
    // which outputs 5
    return 0;
}
```